# Netduino Programmer for .net microframework

Tags: .net-micro-framework, netduino

Where to get Netduino boared in India?
I have been searching for Netduino development board from last one month but not getting it in India(Delhi).If anyone have this information please shere this with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can get it from India at all but you should be able to order one from other countries. I bought mine from [Floris.cc](http://www.pieterfloris.nl/shop/) because it was not available in scandinavia.